# Regex to validate Australian mobile numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, mobile

I have put together this little regex formula that validates numbers to ensure they are a correct [Australian mobile number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Australia#Mobile_phone_numbers_.2804.2C_05.29). The issue I'm having is that the new Telstra number doesn't conform with the standard, therefore it's throwing errors.

Number formats are that it accepts are

0421813629, 0430091460, etc...

though when we use a that has the 3 digit 5 or higher it seems to throw an error, and Telstras new numbers have a 7 in that 3 digit spot

```
/^(?:\+?61|0)4 ?(?:(?:[01] ?[0-9]|2 ?[0-57-9]|3 ?[1-9]|4 ?[7-9]|5 ?[018]) ?[0-9]|3 ?0 ?[0-5])(?: ?[0-9]){5}$/
```

I believe the error has something to do with **?[0-57-9]|3**

Comment: It would be nice if you can inform us about what's the format of Australian phone numbers.

Comment: @m0skit0 i have listed a few examples, there are 10 digits, always starting off 04********

Comment: SO what exactly is the question?  that you want one regex formula to do both?  that won't work, cause you won't know if its a bad number or just a telstra number

Comment: i need it to validate all i believe the |3 (3rd) subset is causing the  issues including the telstra ones that have a 7 in the 3rd digit in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just rewrite the whole thing for you. The regex will compile, but I have yet to test everything. The regex will only work on a string that has been cleaned of spaces (since spaces can be arbitrary and doesn't change the meaning of the phone number). The regex is based on the Wikipedia article. Good luck eyeballing if there is any error, and also good luck maintaining it should they decide to allocate spare block. I wrote the regex by grouping together blocks of 10^7, 10^6, 10^5 and 10^4 numbers that are in use.

```
/^(?:\+?61|0)4(?:[01]\d{3}|(?:2[1-9]|3[0-57-9]|4[7-9]|5[0-15-9]|6[679]|7[3-8]|8[1478]|9[07-9])\d{2}|(?:20[2-9]|444|52[0-6]|68[3-9]|70[0-7]|79[01]|820|890|91[0-4])\d|(?:200[0-3]|201[01]|8984))\d{4}$/
```

If you want to make the regex maintainable, you should write separate **strings** for each of the phone company, then concatenate the strings and call `RegExp` constructor to build the regex from the string. Maybe a bit less efficient, but you will keep your sane when maintaining it.

Comment: this seems to have fixed the problem with the troublesome numbers we had in our data. thanks

Comment: How would you apply the above RegEx in Javascript in ASP.net please?

Comment: @Fernando68: The regex itself is correct for many flavors. However, I don't know the context you are going to use them to give any further suggestion. I suggest that you read the documentation for examples.

Comment: @nhahtdh I tested the above RegEx in https://regex101.com/ online tester as Javascript and it failed. Only in PHP mode does it work. Number tested was 0434999888 for example (not a real mobile).

Comment: @nhahtdh And to note I found this regex is sufficient - /^0[0-8]\d{8}$/g for 10 digit mobile phone numbers, but it does not check if the first two chars are "04". Sorry, I am not interested in +61 or 061, 61, etc. Just the mobile number

Comment: @Fernando68: It's tested against only allocated mobile phone number blocks, [as listed on Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Australia#Mobile_phone_numbers_.2804.29). If you don't need such details, then your simple regex would work. And my regex works on both PHP and JavaScript on regex101.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thank you. Yes it works in regex101. Don't know why it didn't before. Oh well.